# MySQL query using group_start with like - CodeIgniter Active Record

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, phpmyadmin

[image: Table: search_result]

I want to change the current MySQL query to Active Record.

```
 SELECT * FROM search_result
 WHERE experience 
 LIKE 'hello%' OR
 bio LIKE 'hello%' OR 
 FIND_IN_SET('3D Design',skills);
```

I tried the following query, but it showing wrong output.

```
$this->db->from('search_result');
if($keyword){
    $this->db->like('experience', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('bio', $keyword);
}elseif($s_id){
    $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[0]', skills) != ", 0);
    for($x=1; $x < count($s_id); $x++) {
        $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[$x]', skills) != ", 0);
    }
}
............
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this

```
$this->db->from('search_result');
$this->db->where("experience LIKE 'hello%' 
                  OR bio LIKE 'hello%'
                  OR  FIND_IN_SET('3D Design',skills)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two mistakes,

In your raw query you have wildcard `%` only after the search word, so your active record query should be

```
$this->db->like('experience', $keyword, 'after');
$this->db->or_like('bio', $keyword, 'after');
```

In your `elseif`, there is a group of `OR` conditions, you can do this in active record like

```
$this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[0]', skills)"); // no need to compare to 0
    for($x=1; $x < count($s_id); $x++) {
        $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[$x]', skills)");
$this->db->group_end();
```

Reference: [Codeigniter Active Record Query Builder](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: I tried by using `$this->db->group_start();` but still its showing same result.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Once I run the raw query I'm getting 7 results. But for active records its showing only 3 (i.e only the result for `LIKE` condition).

Comment: You can `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();` before `$this->db->get();` to see the compiled query.

Comment: Thanks.. there is some problem with query. its showing like this **Array ( [0] => 3D Design ) SELECT * FROM `search_result` WHERE `experience` LIKE '%hello%' ESCAPE '!' OR `bio` LIKE '%hello%' ESCAPE '!'**

Comment: That is because you have put like condition in if block and find_in_set in else, so only one of it will execute

Comment: yes.. noted. Thank you so much. Somehow your comment helped me.